# (Google Apps Standard) Trick for email retention

Tags: g-suite, gmail

Is there a trick for setting an email retention period(for example delete eMail older than 360 days) in google apps standard edition ?

I need to switch to premiere edition ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Premiere does have some support for policy management, but I don't see any place where you can insist on mail being deleted after x days.

Google support link for policy management: http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=77041

Comment: In this link is explained how to change the mail retention in Google Apps premier edition : 
http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=151128

Comment: Policy Management is probably not relivant to most users. "Policy Management and Message Recovery was made available only to customers who registered Google Apps Premier Edition before August 28, 2008."

Comment: Ok, but what happen when an eMail account is full, the server will say  email full and i will not recieve any mail, or the server auotomatically delete the older mail for make space for new one ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think either editions have such a feature. I have Google Apps Premium and I don't see that option. Google's whole mantra is never delete email again!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, they have an archiving service available for Premium users so that if you delete emails you can recover from the archive.

I don't know if that service includes a retention period option.

Answer (score 0):

Google Apps Premium using Postini mail archiving is currently the **closest** solution. There is no retention period for email in Gmail. If you enable Postini archiving you can then configure a retention period for all email in that domain(s). From the administration panel you can then search and export messages, enable auto-purge, and set the retention period. These features are only available with [Premier Edition](http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/business/security_discovery.html).

Gmail just give you a set amount of storage and leaves it to the user to manage. The Postini storage is completely separate from the Gmail storage. It is archiving every message and prevents anyone other than administrators from delete items from the archive.

I did not see anything that specifically cleans-up someones mailbox in the [Google Apps Marketplace](http://www.google.com/enterprise/marketplace/) but you might have better luck.